Can we have question migration to other stack exchanges?
I would like to be able to vote to close a question to Crypto SE or Money SE.

The question that spurred this feature request: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1305/what-features-of-scrypt-make-tenebrix-gpu-resistant

I've seen questions get migrated to other (existing) SE sites in the past, but I either don't have any such option in my mod menu or I am just being blind/can't find it. I think this may be something a SE employee might have to do, since they are cross-site mods.

@DavidPerry - on other SE sites, there are options to vote to close as "Off Topics (belongs on XYZ.SE)". This feature request is to enable this option here for the specified sites.

There's also the Economics SE that's gearing up for beta. Once it's live I can foresee needing to move questions there as well.

@DavidPerry You do close -> off topic -> belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

@DavidPerry: As a moderator, the migration option is hidden in the menu to vote to close as off-topic. Normal users don't see this text box.

Found that just as you were posting it :)
Thanks for the info Paŭlo!

Migration paths aren't added to sites still in beta, so you'll need to revisit this after you launch. When that does happen, mods need to demonstrate that you've had a good number of posts that should've been migrated to Crypto and Money; devs won't add a migration path unless there's a clear need for it, to avoid opening the door for bad migrations

Migration vote paths are only added (by developers) when there are a quite big number of migrations from one site to other sites.
But this should not hinder you from initiating migrations to other sites (and please, don't simply repost questions):
♦ Moderators (for your site, your new Moderators Pro Tempore, as well as quite a number of SE employees) can moderate questions everywhere.
They will often (other than in really obvious cases) consult with moderators of the target site before doing so (since the target site's moderators have a better grasp on what is on-topic there).
So, the way to go would be to flag the question, and put the appropriate message for moderators:

You can additionally vote to close as off-topic, then your vote will appear in the "migrated by ..." list on the closed question after a moderator migrates it.

This doesn't really address his request, which is to add migration paths

You are right, I added some sentences about this.
